Count occurences (rows) between dates (SPSS)
I have data on surgeries, every row represent a patient with a performed surgery. I wish to answer the question: How many procedures has this surgeon performed in the last year (at that time of the surgery)?
Here is some example data:
DATA LIST LIST / patient_id (A20) operator_id (A20) procedure_date (SDATE10).
BEGIN DATA.
1,pseudo_001,2024/02/01
2,pseudo_002,2024/07/11
3,pseudo_002,2023/08/10
4,pseudo_003,2024/03/01
5,pseudo_004,2024/08/01
6,pseudo_004,2024/07/02
7,pseudo_004,2024/01/15
8,pseudo_003,2023/01/19
END DATA.

It is an easy task to create a variable with the date 1 year back:
COMPUTE procedure_date_1yback=DATESUM(procedure_date, -1, "years", 'closest').
VARIABLE LEVEL procedure_date_1yback(SCALE).
FORMATS procedure_date_1yback(SDATE10).
VARIABLE WIDTH procedure_date_1yback(11).
EXECUTE.

But from here I am lost. I have managed to get the amount of performed procedures at the "year" before using AGGREGATE on both operator and the "year".
Here is how I would like it to be:
DATA LIST LIST / patient_id (A20) operator_id (A20) procedure_date (SDATE10) performed_procedures (A20).
BEGIN DATA.
1,pseudo_001,2024/02/01,1
2,pseudo_002,2024/07/11,2
3,pseudo_002,2023/08/10,1
4,pseudo_003,2024/03/01,1
5,pseudo_004,2024/08/01,3
6,pseudo_004,2024/07/02,2
7,pseudo_004,2024/01/15,1
8,pseudo_003,2023/01/19,1
END DATA.


This is a really nice question, thank you! I created an SPSS solution, and just for comparison also made a very simple Excel solution.

This is one of the rare occasions that Excel offers a much simpler solution - with simple countifs (compare to my SPSS answer):
=countIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,"<="&C2,C:C,">="&D2)

when column B is the operator, column C is the operation date, column D is the date of one year before the operation.


SPSS solution - for each row attach all the operation dates of the relevant operator in new columns, then loop though those columns and count the relevant dates:
* first recreating your example data.
DATA LIST LIST / patient_id (A20) operator_id (A20) procedure_date (SDATE10).
BEGIN DATA.
1,pseudo_001,2024/02/01
2,pseudo_002,2024/07/11
3,pseudo_002,2023/08/10
4,pseudo_003,2024/03/01
5,pseudo_004,2024/08/01
6,pseudo_004,2024/07/02
7,pseudo_004,2024/01/15
8,pseudo_003,2023/01/19
END DATA.      
sort cases by operator_id procedure_date.

* duplicate the data to work on a wide version separately.
dataset name orig.
dataset copy wide.
dataset activate wide.
* creating an operation index number to use for restructre.
compute opN=1.
if $casenum>1 and operator_id=lag(operator_id) opN=lag(opN)+1.
format opN(f6).
* now ready for restructure: every operator will have one row with each operation date in a separate column.
casestovars /id=operator_id /index=opN /separator="_" /drop patient_id.
* creating a dynamic list of the operation date columns.
spssinc select variables macroname="!alldates" /PROPERTIES PATTERN="procedure_date_*".

dataset activate orig.
COMPUTE procedure_1yback=DATESUM(procedure_date, -1, "years", 'closest').
FORMATS procedure_1yback(SDATE10).
* bringing the operation date column back to the original data so that each operation date can be compared to all the operator's operation dates.
match files /file=*/table=wide/by operator_id.
compute Noperations=0.
* looping through all the operation date columns (using previously defined list).
do repeat dt=!alldates .
    if dt<=procedure_date and dt>=procedure_1yback Noperations=Noperations+1.
end repeat.
EXECUTE.

